# How to get constraints on indexes?

Tags: database, postgresql, unique-constraint

I'm creating something that needs to collect all types of data on your database, including the types of constraints used by each column. Unfortunately, it appears there is two ways to add constraints to a column (or maybe even more that I'm unaware of), you can either add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, or you can add an INDEX with UNIQUE on it.

I have this query:

`select * from information_schema.table_constraints WHERE constraint_type='UNIQUE';`

But the problem is that it does not detect UNIQUE constraints that are applied to an INDEX, it only detects UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS on their own, for example, it cannot find this:

`Indexes:
    "index_videos_on_slug" UNIQUE, btree (slug)`

Does anyone know of a way I can get this information? Thanks.

Comment: `pg_index.indisunique` (in the pg_catalog schema) Note `information_schema` is built on top of pg_catalog, and contains only the elements dictated by the comittee)

Comment: @joop, I really think you should post that as an answer

Comment: Hmm, how would I go about linking that information to tables and column names? It looks like gobbledygook when I query it. I presume I have to link the relid's somehow?

Comment: [consider it done] When querying the catalogs, in most cases you end up with at least 4 or 5 joined tables that need to be consulted.

Comment: Note that we tend to discourage editing solutions into questions round here; we like to keep questions and answers separate. If the accepted answer doesn't contain the full solution, you could propose an edit to that, or provide your own answer.

Comment: @IMSoP No worries, I've removed it, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [the postgres catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-index.html) live in the `pg_catalog` schema
- `information_schema` is built on top of this (as a set of views)
- information_schema is not complete, only the stuff that is dictated by the ANSI committee is implemented (more or less the GCD of all implementations)
- indexes are not part of SQL (but most/all SQL implementations have them)

---

`pg_index.indisunique` (in the pg_catalog schema) is what you want.

BTW: if you want to promote an existing index to a constraint, you can use the  [alter ... using ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html) syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE ... ADD constraint ... USING your_index_name;
```

Comment: Thanks. I found `pg_stat_all_indexes` which points to the `indexrelid` in `pg_index`, and then it's just a matter of checking the `indisunique` for `t` or `f`. If you can think of a better way, let me know.

Comment: Dont forget to check for the schemaname (pg_namespace), especially if you have separate schemas for development/test/etc.

Comment: @b0xxed1n note that `'t'` and `'f'` are just the text output for `true` and `false`, so `WHERE indisunique = 't'`, `WHERE indisunique = true` and just `WHERE indisunique` all mean the same thing.